# Randomise or shred memory of an application

Tags: linux, bash, security, password, memory

Is it possible to randomise or shred memory of a particular application just after its life ends, or better, whenever it deallocates some memory?

A command-line utility like this would be perfect:

shred-memory [options]  [{params to the application...}]

Comment: aren't thinks like PIC and stack smashing and stuff supposed to help with apps trying to read an apps memory?

Answer (score 4):

Linux (like any modern multi-process OSes, I would hope) ensures that processes only get zeroed out pages when they allocate memory. So a process cannot read the memory formerly used by another process.

Under Linux, the zeroing out happens when a page is allocated, not when it is freed. This leaves two ways of reading the memory formerly used by a process:

- exploit a kernel bug
- dump the contents of the RAM or swap (which requires root or physical access)

A patch to the Linux kernel to allow zeroing out pages as soon as they are freed was proposed ([`sanitize_mem` episode 1](http://lwn.net/Articles/334747/), [`sanitize_mem` episode 2](http://lwn.net/Articles/335698/)), but as far as I can tell not accepted.

In practice, the biggest window for attack is the swap space (which can retain data for a long time), and even that is not trivial for the attacker (who needs to steal the disk, and sort out the jumble of pages). It's also the easiest to fix: encrypt the swap space with `dm-crypt`.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Gilles answer:

- You may [lock page in-memory](http://linux.die.net/man/2/mlock) to prevent swapping (unless you know what you are doing - like storing password - it is bad idea and it may affect performance of system)
- You may override `free` function to sanatize memory by hand using `LD_LIBRARY_PRELOAD`

Answer (score 0):

There are utilities for wiping memory, but it would be after the program in question had exited and freed up its memory.  I know of nothing that will specifically wipe the memory allocated by a particular program.

Check out "smem" (among others) from the "secure_delete" suite at [thc.org](http://www.thc.org) for wiping free memory of a live system.